# Angle of view based on Ellipse

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I need to calculate the angle of view of Camera to Object preferably in a 180 degree plane (angles ranging from 0 - 180), providing me direction.

I have so far tried using Ellipse angle or calculating one by proportion of width and height multiplied by 90, but they are not as accurate (basically I see failure & success in proceeding calculation at the same angle.

Attached are multiple views of an circle. The grid below in background (only in test) will help us understand the orientation. There is no such guidance available in real life condition but the radius of object is known.

(Can't post image due to less than desired reputation)

Comment: Image links - ![reference circle/ellipse image](https://imgur.com/Ko2i7lW)

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I am currently using a virtual point on the circle, which is calculated using a random angle (to orientation). Based on my view, the previously assigned random angle doesn't align at the same location unless the angle of view matches that of the first instance (when random angle was assigned).
I need to determine the angle of view - camera directly on top, or pointing from left - right or from left to right.

Comment: Is there any other information required?

Comment: I think you should do a quick gut-check and calculate how much distortion you expect over what angular range.  I fear that you may be running near pixel resolutions limits and or line width type issues as the distortion will be very small at first.

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear I have a separate method for distortion correction using findHomography which does a good job.
The image being captured is 640x480 irrespective of phone being used and byte[] being stored from onPreviewFrame.
The challenge is that the angle of view has a high impact on the random point being taken and keeps changing. I need a sure shot way to know if the image needs rotation (or mathematical adjustment to desired angle) so that the point is at exact same place irrespective of angle of view.

Comment: I don't think I conveyed my meaning.  To determine angle, you are measuring the distortion of the circle due to viewing angle.  I am saying that mathematically you can estimate how much the circle actually changes in pixel space... and I fear that your pixel space is too small to do this in the angular resolution you want.

Comment: This is not the real object that I am working on, so there are more contours within the circle to work on.
Also we don't necessarily need to use this approach to arrive at an angle, any other suggestions is most appreciated.
I am going to check on how to use area (if that is what you meant by pixel space) to estimate the viewing angle.

Comment: Tried minAreaRect on the biggest contour, but always seem to be having -45 degree angle, which is not particularly useful.